# R - Cluster x number of events within y time period

Tags: r, date, time, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that has 59k entries recorded over 63 years, I need to identify clusters of events with the criteria being:

6 or more events within 6 hours

Each event has a unique ID, time HH:MM:SS and date DD:MM:YY, an output would ideally have a cluster ID, the eventS that took place within each cluster, and start and finish time and date.

Thinking about the problem in R we would need to look at every date/time and count the number of events in the following 6 hours, if the number is 6 or greater save the event IDs, if not move onto the next date and perform the same task. I have taken a data extract that just contains EventID, Date, Time and Year.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/DataStack.csv

If I come up with anything in the meantime I will post below.

Update: Having taken a break to think about the problem I have a new approach.

Add 6 hours to the Date/Time of each event then count the number of events that fall within the start end time, if there are 6 or more take the eventIDs and assign them a clusterID. Then move onto the next event and repeat 59k times as a loop.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301290/which-data-clustering-algorithm-is-appropriate-to-detect-an-unknown-number-of-cl?rq=1) in the meantime (it's not R-specific, but perhaps still relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use clustering. It's the wrong tool. And the wrong term. You are not looking for abstract "clusters", but something much simpler and much more well defined. In particular, your data is 1 dimensional, which makes things a lot easier than the multivariate case omnipresent in clustering.

Instead, **sort your data** and use a **sliding window**.

If your data is sorted, and time[x+5] - time[x] < 6 hours, then these events satisfy your condition.

Sorting is O(n log n), but highly optimized. The remainder is O(n) in a single pass over your data. This will beat every single clustering algorithm, because they don't exploit your data characteristics.

Comment: Now that sounds much better! What package would you suggest to perform a sliding window analysis? Also, apologies for sounding a bit green here but I do not fully understand, I think your saying that the process only looks at the data once instead of having to loop through for every event in the dataset. Thanks Again!

Comment: I don't use R, so I cannot give you package recommendations. You might be able to get away with just shifting the sorted data set by 5, then computing the time difference. Any `true` in this array indicates there is a sequence of 5 entries that satisfy your threshold. Merge adjacent `true`s for larger clusters.

Comment: Going to repost this question with a better title struggling to get the 'sliding window' working. Thanks for all your help.